Secret door in a shower
I'm trying to find a movie I watched once. I can't remember the name or actors. 
Its about a brown haired girl who moves into an apartment, she soon finds a secret door in the shower which leads her into a house back in time.
She befriends a blonde lady which eventually follows the girl back and tells everyone that the blonde lady is her cousin.
The two women switch lives until they are running out of time and have to decide to stay or go back to there own time.
Its not a box office type of movie, it aired on TV not sure what channel maybe hallmark, USA, lifetime, tnt, etc.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Sounds like the tv mini series "Lost in Austin": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_in_Austen

This looks like the TV Mini-Series Lost in Austin.
From the Episode 1 description in Wikipedia it mentions the door in the bathroom that you mention:

...discovers Elizabeth Bennet, a character from Pride and Prejudice, in a nightgown in her bathroom; but when Elizabeth disappears, she brushes the incident off as a dream. Amanda explains to her mother that Jane Austen's novel has shown her that she can set higher standards for a husband for herself, and taught her to believe in true love. Elizabeth appears in Amanda's bathroom again, this time dressed for travel.
Amanda steps through the secret doorway in the wall that Elizabeth has shown her, and finds herself at Longbourn, the house of the Bennet family, near the beginning of the novel. Amanda is trapped in this world while Elizabeth is in 21st-century London.

Here is a trailer on youtube: 




Not too sure, but based on the information you are sharing, I'd guess it could be:
Mullholand Drive
I do not specifically remember a secret door being in the shower but your blonde lady bit being her cousin seems to be from the movie.
Also, the film has many intertwined, weird, dimension things happening which could be confused with going back in time.
Plot from Wikipedia is here:

It tells the story of an aspiring actress named Betty Elms (Watts), newly arrived in Los Angeles, who meets and befriends an amnesiac woman (Harring) hiding in an apartment which belongs to Betty's aunt. The story includes several other seemingly unrelated vignettes that eventually interlock, as well as some surreal and darkly comic scenes and images that relate to the cryptic narrative.

Trailer here:



